# How can I add a row for Unpivoted data that is at the hourly level and I want to display it at the 15 min interval

Tags: ssis

I am very new to SSIS so the answer to this might be very basic.

I have data that is coming in at an hourly level, meaning that a single record would have 25 columns (hour 1 - 25 with the 25th being null for DST) I have unpivoted the data to show a single column with the hour.  I now need to display this data at the 15 min interval.

My plan is to duplicate the row of data for hour 1, say it is 8 and divide by 4 and now each 15 min interval would be 2

What can I do to accomplish this goal?

I have no clue where to start, looking for ideas.

Comment: Unclear.  What would your desired output look like?   1 column with 100 rows (25x4)?

Comment: Yes that would be the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that this is a terrible approach to whatever it is you really want to do, but since you haven't asked about what you really want to do, I'll treat your question as academic.

If you have to do this in the dataflow, you could write a script transformation with a loop that creates 4 output rows for every input row and does the division.

Personally I would do this in a stored procedure that gets called after the data is initially loaded into a staging table on the destination server:

SELECT from the staging table, cross joined to a CTE with 4 rows, and dividing the value by 4.